# How to create a spline from an AutoCAD .DWG file in 3ds Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, modeling

I'm kinda new to 3ds max, and I don't know AutoCAD.

I'm trying to create a line (spline?) to outline a building's basement plan, then I will extrude it and go on with the modelling.

To create the spline, I imported the DWG file (removed the inside, only the outside lines remain), and I'm following it to create an editable spline.

Now I'm looking for an easy way to create the line.

What I'm currently doing is, I'm making a "bad" line, i.e. the vertices are near the corners, then I'm dragging all the corners to their appropriate position by zooming in.

But this takes too long. Is there any way that I can define the points one by one, then select all the points and create an editable spline from the set of corner points ?

In this case, all the points are corners. So no smooths, beziers etc.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the .DWG file into adobe Illustrator then save the spline from illustrator like this: Click file save and name it whatever. Then in the Illustrator Options, change the version to Illustrator 8 and click okay. For some reason max likes Illustrator 8...

Now import your .ai file into 3ds Max and convert to a spline.

That's how I do it.